# A RenderFlex overflowed by 1.3 pixels on the right

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, mobile, flutter-layout

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Text(
          Cart().freeDeliveryString,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/');
          },
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            primary: Colors.black,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(),
            elevation: 0,
          ),
          child: Text(
            'Add More İtems',
            style:
              Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4!.copyWith(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: Please check out the ["How to ask a good question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article to improve your question and your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: [This documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints) will be a valuable resource for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping any or both children of your row with an `Expanded` widget

Wrapping only your `Text` widget with an `Expanded` widget will be enough to solve your error.

```dart
   Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                'Cart().freeDeliveryString',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/');
              },
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                primary: Colors.black,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(),
                elevation: 0,
              ),
              child: Text(
                'Add More İtems',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4!.copyWith(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
```